# broken nautilus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

Not sure how this happened but now the "Places" menu on my Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick opens "VLC" for each of the item on this menu e.g. If I select "Home Folder", VLC opens up **and** no nautilus file browser opens up...

please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional handling of MIME types (filetypes) is defined by the Mimeapps.list settings file, located at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Edit it by typing `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and removing offensive entries for `inode/directory` for things other than Nautilus. For example, delete lines like `inode/directory=vlc.desktop;`, which specifies VLC as the application to open folders.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/27330/broken-launchers-for-panel/27332#27332